# Is there an update lately with Azure DataFactory V1 for Credentials' expiring date?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've been using Azure Datafactory V1 for a long time now, but lately, I've been having troubles with credentials expiring.
A slice of the error message I get is:

"Credential operation error: The authentication token for your linked service has expired.
 Please reauthorize the linked service and re-run the slice/activity window."
Even though I don't have any expiration constraint.

I have to redeploy all of my Pipelines within my DataFactory in order to make it work again.
This happened twice this week (6 days interval).

I don't know if this is due to some updates, or a way to force migration to Datafactory V2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the authentication type from OAuth to Service Principle.  OAuth tokens expire.  Service Principle fetches new OAuth tokens on its own.  Do you need instructions for this change?

On another note, I *strongly* encourage you to migrate to V2.

Comment: Yes I might need some instructions to do so. And yes, I am going to migrate to V2, but I need my data up to date for now. Thank you!